# How to transfer the tensorflow trained CNN neural network to the input format of lrp_toolbox_master?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, classification, pickle

I use python and [tensorflow CNN](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf) for text classification.
[lrp_toolbox](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox) is a explain model of the neural network, it will provide the reason of classification of neural network model like "CNN", "RNN".
 The input of  [lrp_toolbox](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox) is trained "CNN" model with the following [format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/872eH.png)

I don't know how to make this format from the [*sess*](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) or *graph* of tensorflow CNN.
I try to pickle the *sess* use code:

`filename = 'trainedCNN_model_%s.pickle' % str(current_step)
 pickle.dump(sess, open(filename, 'wb'))`,

but it fails and shows `TypeError: can't pickle module objects`.

And actually, I think sess can't meet the input format of [lrp_toolbox](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox). The example input of *lrp_toolbox* is text format like

`Linear 2 3
-2.01595799878 -2.05379403106 0.688953420218 1.20338836267 -1.7518249173 -1.90515935663
-0.519917325831 0.400368842573 0.0699950389094
Tanh
Linear 3 3
-1.18542075899 -1.62921811225 0.134698917906 0.111469267787 1.85227669488 -0.350827317469 0.102194311719 -1.67678396935 0.256312518679
0.116095097279 -0.0138454065897 0.0469443958438
Tanh
Linear 3 2
1.10940574175 0.26799513777 2.51842248017 -1.5497671807 -0.606042655911 0.197763706892
-0.115832556216 0.115832556216
SoftMax`

Here is the [manual](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox/blob/master/doc/manual/manual.pdf) of [lrp_toolbox](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a trained neural network model (be it trained with Tensorflow or some other neural network toolbox), you basically just have a set of weights and biases as floating point values.

Now, in order to convert this model to the plain text file format of the [lrp_toolbox](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox), such that you can subsequently explain your model with the [Python Implementation of the lrp_toolbox](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox/tree/master/python), you simply need to manually write a function that saves your model weights+biases in a plain text file, following the format described in the Section **The shared plain text file format** pages 16-17 of the [manual](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox/blob/master/doc/manual/manual.pdf).

This means, that you have to write a function very similar to the function `_write_txt(model, path)` of the [lrp_toolbox](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox/blob/master/python/model_io.py), that takes as first input say your trained Tensorflow model, and as second input the output text file path, and that writes all the weights+biases (as well as the sequence of other layers of your model: pooling and activation) in this output file in human-readable raw text.

Then, you can load your model in the lrp_toolbox with something like `model_io.read('my_model.txt')`, and perform LRP on some data (for reading the data, you can use `data_io.read('my_input')`). See a full usage example [here](https://github.com/sebastian-lapuschkin/lrp_toolbox/blob/master/python/lrp_cnn_demo.py).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some method, when you need to serialize object by pickle.

> TypeError: can't pickle module objects.
>   As this error message explain, sess is not be implemented method for serialize sess object. And also, I can not see what value the sess has. 
>   Could you explain how you made the sess?

ref) https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: sess is a class for running TensorFlow operations. 
 [link]https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session[link]

Comment: sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
    with sess.as_default():

Comment: In my understanding, lrp_toolbox has a ability to load trained model from pickle format. Hence you need to understand how to save to pickle format by tensorflow.
ref) https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model